# String limitation in Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, string

[image]I am sending some data as a **string** to a function in **Smart Contract** but it seems that there is a limitation. I can send this string:

**1643934348.9036129,1643934348.9495316?1487.4277,1627.4347?0.1,0.0?280.0002,230.0002?0.117,0.0?119.7019,119.7021?0.0,0.0?0.7999,0.7999?0.0,0.0?5,5?49.6,49.6?0.0,0.0**

But when I send following I get an error of **Error: types/values length mismatch**:

**1643934348.9036129,1643934348.9495316,1643934348.9934864?1427.4377,1427.4377,1427.4377?0.0,0.0,0.0?260.0002,260.0002,260.0002?0.117,0.0,0.0?119.7019,119.7021,119.7021?0.0,0.0,0.0?0.7999,0.7999,0.7999?0.0,0.0,-0.117?5,5,5?49.6,49.6,49.7?0.0,0.0,0.0**

Also just to mention if I send only one column of time stamps then I can send alot more(checked till 100 timestamps) e.g.

**1643934348.9036129, 1643934348.9495316, 1643934348.9934864, 1643934349.0395827, 1643934349.0854738, 1643934349.1314104, 1643934349.1776688, 1643934349.2217667, 1643934349.2655103, 1643934349.3115413, 1643934349.3555484, 1643934349.402903, 1643934349.447666, 1643934349.4947226, 1643934349.5415196, 1643934349.5869575, 1643934349.6325715, 1643934349.677625, 1643934349.725675, 1643934349.7696273**

Here is just a simple example code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract input_string {
string data;

function input_data(string memory _data) public returns (bool _success) {
    data = _data;
    return true;
 }

function see_data() public view returns(string memory) {
    return data;
 }

}
```

I did some research and tried some answers but no success e.g. I increased the gas from 3000000 to 8000000 but still not working.

So like can someone explain the length or format of the string that can be sent in a smart contract or what other methods I can use for this.

Comment: How are send to the contract those strings? I tried the contract in remix and it worked without issues. I was able to send those strings.

Comment: Did you manage to send second string that i attached because thats the one giving error and i am also using remix. You can see the code and now I have also added image of remix settings. So let me know what is different in your environment

Comment: Yes, I tried all the strings in the question. I just surrounded by double quotes in the input box: `"164393434....49.7?0.0,0.0,0.0"`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes it works when I put them in double quotes. Just one weird thing is if I expand input field and enter string it gives error. But if I enter string without expanding input field it works. lol